# Can I add more luggage after doing the on-line check-in in Ryanair?

Tags: air-travel, planning, luggage, ryanair

I will be travelling with Ryanair in a few weeks. Currently I have a printer so I can do the check in and print the tickets.

I am not yet sure if I will increase the weight in my luggage. I will only know this in a few weeks and I won't have access to a printer any more.

My question is if I can add more checked in luggage after doing the on-line check-in. If yes do I have to print the ticket again?

Note: The answer from user3470 is valuable but doesn't answer my question. I plan to take only  hand luggage but I might have to add checked in luggage later. As I described before, by than I won't have access to a printer. Can I still use the same "printed ticket" even if I add luggage?

Answer (score 8):

[Ryanair's terms and conditions](http://www.ryanair.com/en/terms-and-conditions#regulations-checkedbaggage) do not allow you to upgrade a 15 kg bag to a 20 kg bag. If you have booked 15 kg, you will have to pay for a possible excess. Currently the price is 20 EUR per kilo. You might be better off by booking 20 kg from the start.

It is possible to check in (additional) luggage at the airport, even after the online check-in. However this will be more expensive than doing it online. Also note that a maximum of two (checked) bags is allowed by passenger.

Comment: That's useful information. My question is still valid. One of the persons flying with me didn't buy check-in luggage. Is it possible to buy it after buying after the on-line check in?

Comment: Actually, Ryanair allows anything provided you have enough cash.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatly it doens't fully answer.

Comment: @nsn What was your experience in the end?

Comment: @feklee I was traveling with someone without checked in luggage and asked to add an extra piece of luggage. I circumvented the problem.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2015-04-16 WEST it seems possible. After having printed my 
boarding pass, here’s what I did:

1. Clicked *Manage Booking* near the top of the Ryanair page.
2. On the next page, clicked: *Add checked bags*
3. On another page, selected as option *Add Services-
   Baggage/Transfers/Car Parking*. In the section *Retrieve my
   booking*, I entered my reservation number and the last digits of my
   credit card.
4. On the next page, added a 15kg bag for 25.00 EUR. Clicked
   *Continue*.

On the final page, I could have entered my credit card data, and clicked
submit, but I didn’t really need a bag, so I stopped here.

**Beware:** When I started writing this message, I paused during the
process to write the text and take screen shots, and after clicking
*Continue* in step four, I got an error message: *“It is not possible to
change this reservation online for one or more of the following reasons:
1)One or more passengers are already checked in on this flight. 2)You
have exceeded the minimum time allowed to change a reservation online.”*
As it worked the second time, I assume that the reason for the error was
number two.

Comment: that's good information. I assume you don't know if the printed has to be printed again?!

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was made Ryanair has introduced digital tickets through their app ([android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryanair.cheapflights&hl=pt), [ios](https://itunes.apple.com/pt/app/ryanair-cheap-flights/id504270602?ls=1&mt=8)). Therefore printing tickets before travelling or finding a place to print them while traveling is no longer a problem in case you possess either an Android or IOS enabled device.

This means that changes can be made at any time and a ticket can be easily obtained again.